# Django HTML Tags - Merge For Loop with Conditional Statement

Tags: html, django, tags

I am using Django and I am wondering if there is a way to modify the tags below so that the for loop stops iterating once a specific condition is met?

```
webpage.html
<div>
{% for person in crew.crew_set.all %}
   {% if person.job|stringformat:'s' == 'Supervisor'  %}
       <div>Supervisor</div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The code above results in "Supervisor" being written 50 times.  Can I merge the two tags or use a break statement somehow so "Supervisor" is only listed once?

I'm not listing my models / views because I'm really just trying to get a better understanding of how to use tags on my html pages.

**Details:**

Models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Jobs(models.Model):
    jobcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Crew(models.Model):
    jobnumber = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Views.py

```
class PersonPageView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('jobs_set', Jobs.objects.select_related('jobnumber')),
        Prefetch('crew_set', Crew.objects.select_related('person'))
    )
    template_name = '_person_info.html'
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - You bet.  I have update the post.  I suspect the best way to handle this is a Boolean field in the Person model, but I'm curious if the for loop and if statement tags can somehow be combined.  Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: So what is `crew` in the template? That seems to be a `Person` because of the `.crew_set`?

Comment: I am trying to pull the 'role' field from the Crew model.   The Crew model ties the Person model and the Job model (which tracks the job number and name of the job) together.   So for instance, the Crew model could track if someone was the Supervisor on Job #2039.  A person can do multiple roles on a job, so that person could also be the "Survey Specialist" on job #2039 which would be another record..

Comment: A person can also be a Supervisor on 50 different jobs which would create 50 different records on the Crew table.  I figured tracking the individual jobs in the Job model, and individual people in the Person model would cut down on duplicate records (one record in the job table for each unique job, and one record in the person table for each unique person).  Then bring those together in the Crew table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* do this in the template. Templates should be used to implement *rendering* logic, not *business logic*. Templates are not very efficient, but also deliberately lack all sorts of tooling to prevent people from doing this.

You can use an `Exists` subquery to check this, this will also boost efficiency:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


class PersonPageView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('jobs_set', Jobs.objects.select_related('jobnumber')),
        Prefetch('crew_set', Crew.objects.select_related('person')),
    ).annotate(
        is_supervisor=Exists(
            Crew.objects.filter(person_id=OuterRef('pk'), role='Supervisor')
        )
    )
    template_name = '_person_info.html'
```

The `person` will then have an extra attribute `.is_supervisor`, so you can use:

```
{% if person.is_supervisor %}
    …
{% endif %}
```